# Make Android Wear notification clickable without the action icon

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am sending a notification from the watch, and I want the notification to be clickable, i.e., it opens an activity when clicked. Here is what it comes out to look like

[image: notification]
<sub>(source: [macnn.com](http://max.macnn.com/article_images/1415020145-md-sonosandroidwearleaktb.jpg))</sub>

But, I do not want the play icon to show, just want the plain notification look. Even if I set an empty action icon, the icon space is still taken and I cannot fit text into that space. Is there a way to free up that icon space for text to show?

Code as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Tracking")
            .setContentText("Tap to open.")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launchbg))
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.empty_icon, "blah", pendingSaveIntent)                 
            .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                    .setContentAction(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

[setHintHideIcon(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setHintHideIcon%28boolean%29) hides the icon.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Tracking")
        .setContentText("Tap to open.")
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launchbg))
        .setLocalOnly(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.empty_icon, "blah", pendingSaveIntent)                 
        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                .setHintHideIcon(true)
                .setContentAction(0));
```

Comment: Tried it, no icon is shown, but the space where the play icon was is still not useable, i.e., title and text would not extend into that space, but shows ellipsis instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to Accomplish this you will have to create a Custom RemotViews Object and pass in a custom layout to the notification via:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews("PACKAGENAMEWHERELAYOUTEXISTS", R.layout.custom_layout);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                         .setContent(remoteView);
```

see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#RemoteViews(java.lang.String,int)

for Remote Views.

and for Setting Content:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContent(android.widget.RemoteViews)

Comment: Do you have code samples that work on Android Wear? http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html says "Notifications using RemoteViews are stripped of custom layouts". When I tried, I just get a blank white background. I know I can build a custom notification, but hoping I can avoid creating an Activity just for this simple thing.